# ¿Cómo cambio el color del borde de fuera de un button?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, sass

Estoy haciendo un login con Bootstrap y quería hacer un cambio a la línea exterior del botón que es de color azul a rosa. Probé lo siguiente pero no funciona, pude cambiar todo menos lo que les comento:

[image: Borde de color azul]

El bootsrap que utilizo:

```
 <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

html de mi button:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-4 rose">Iniciar Sesion</button>
```

```
.btn-primary {
  background-color: $principal !important;
  border-radius: 20px !important;
  border-color: #e21983 !important;
}

.btn-primary:focus {
  outline-color: #e21983 !important; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que hice fue lo siguiente:

- Quito todos los bordes y sombras por defecto que incluye el botón de Bootstrap, con la propiedad `outline: none` y `box-shadow: none`.
- Se usa la declaración [**`!important`**](https://desarrolloweb.com/articulos/declaracion-important-css.html) para que las propiedades tomen precedencia sobre los estilos que traía el botón de Bootstrap.
- Y por último, le di un `border` con el color especificado, un grosor de `5px` y el tipo de línea `solid`, así:

  ```
   .btn-primary:focus {
     outline: none !important;
     box-shadow: none !important;
     border: #e21983 5px solid !important;
   }
  ```

Ejemplo funcional:

```css
.contenedor {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 10px;
}

.focused:focus {
  outline: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  border: #e21983 5px solid !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="contenedor">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Default Focus</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary focused">Custom Focus</button>
</div>
```